# euler_equation from sympy.calculus.euler producing wrong derivatives

Tags: sympy, derivative

I've been trying to get the first variation of a functional that depends on the function phi, and its first and second gradients. I'm probably doing something wrong.

the function phi:

```
φ(x, y, t)
```

its first gradient gradient_1_phi:

```
⎡∂               ∂             ⎤
⎢──(φ(x, y, t))  ──(φ(x, y, t))⎥
⎣∂x              ∂y            ⎦
```

its second gradient gradient_2_phi:

```
⎡   2                  2             ⎤
⎢  ∂                  ∂              ⎥
⎢ ───(φ(x, y, t))   ─────(φ(x, y, t))⎥
⎢   2               ∂y ∂x            ⎥
⎢ ∂x                                 ⎥
⎢                                    ⎥
⎢   2                  2             ⎥
⎢  ∂                  ∂              ⎥
⎢─────(φ(x, y, t))   ───(φ(x, y, t)) ⎥
⎢∂y ∂x                 2             ⎥
⎣                    ∂y              ⎦
```

For the sake of simplicity, I split the functional in three parts, one containing phi, another its first gradient, and the last containing the second gradient. These are potential_PFC, regularizers_PFC_1, and regularizers_PFC_2 respectively.

Problem: when computing the first variation of regularizers_PFC_2 wrt the second gradient gradient_2_phi, the cross derivatives disappear.

In regularizers_PFC_2, I would expect to get

```
⎡        4                     4                        4                             ⎤
⎢       ∂                     ∂                       ∂                               ⎥
⎢- 1.0⋅───(φ(x, y, t)) - 1.0⋅───(φ(x, y, t)) - 2.0⋅ ──────(φ(x, y, t)) = 0, True, True⎥
⎢        4                     4                      2  2                            ⎥
⎣      ∂x                    ∂y                     ∂x ∂y                             ⎦
```

but I get

```
⎡        4                     4                            ⎤
⎢       ∂                     ∂                             ⎥
⎢- 1.0⋅───(φ(x, y, t)) - 1.0⋅───(φ(x, y, t)) = 0, True, True⎥
⎢        4                     4                            ⎥
⎣      ∂x                    ∂y                             ⎦
```

Here is the code, I appreciate very much and suggestion.

```
from sympy import Symbol, Function
from sympy.calculus.euler import euler_equations
from sympy import tensorcontraction, tensorproduct, eye
from sympy.tensor.array import derive_by_array
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()

La = Lb = Lc = 1

t     = Symbol('t')
x     = Symbol('x')
y     = Symbol('y')

phi   = Function('phi')(x,y,t)
gradient_1_phi = Function('gradient_1_phi')(x,y,t)
gradient_2_phi = Function('gradient_2_phi')(x,y,t)

grad_1_phi = derive_by_array(phi,[x,y])
grad_2_phi = derive_by_array(grad_1_phi,[x,y])
regularizers_PFC_1 = -Lb*tensorcontraction(tensorproduct(grad_1_phi,grad_1_phi), (0, 1))
regularizers_PFC_2 = +0.5*Lc*tensorcontraction(tensorproduct(grad_2_phi,grad_2_phi),(0,1,2,3))
potential_PFC = La*(0.5*(1.0-0.2)*phi**2 + 0.25*phi*phi*phi*phi)
d_regularizers_PFC_1 = euler_equations(regularizers_PFC_1, [phi,gradient_1_phi,gradient_2_phi], [x,y,t])
d_regularizers_PFC_2 = euler_equations(-regularizers_PFC_2, [phi,gradient_1_phi,gradient_2_phi], [x,y,t])
```